# Conditional operation on one column of Pandas DF based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the pandas dataframe below with 2 columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quantity':[15, 30, 35, 20], 'sign':[1,1,2,1]})
```

I want to apply a conditional statement and multiply the `quantity` value in each row by -1 if the corresponding `sign` value in that row is equal to 2. I don't want to create a new column. I just want to apply this to the `quantity` column.

I have tried using `.loc` and `.apply(lamda x:)`, but I must not be applying them correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equality and multiple by scalar:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quantity':[15, 30, 35, 20], 'sign':[1,1,2,1]})

df.loc[df['sign'].eq(2), 'quantity'] *=  - 1
print (df)
   quantity  sign
0        15     1
1        30     1
2       -35     2
3        20     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was easy. I'm a python noob coming from working mostly in R before.